# Spark convert json data to DataFrame using Scala

Tags: apache-spark

Input one.txt file

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]
```

Expected out:

```
a       b        c
1,11,1  2,12,1   3,13,3
```

Could you please provide the solution in a Spark dataFrame using scala?

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JSON_Sample").master("local[1]") getOrCreate()
val data = """[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]"""    //one.txt
val df = spark.read.text("./src/main/scala/resources/text/one.txt").toDF()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is python version of running code with spark. if you are able to convert it then it is fine otherwise let me know i will do it.

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]))
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
| 11| 12| 13|
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+

df.agg(*[concat_ws(",",collect_list(col(i))).alias(i) for i in df.columns]).show()
+------+------+------+
|     a|     b|     c|
+------+------+------+
|1,11,1|2,12,2|3,13,3|
+------+------+------+
```

For scala Spark :

```
import spark.implicits._ 
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JSON_Sample").master("local[1]") getOrCreate() 
val jsonStr = """[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]""" 

val df= spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonStr :: Nil)) 

val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "collect_list")).toMap df.agg(exprs).show()
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh,  I have tried my local and am able to read the data. But the aggregate function is not working & needs to find a solution.     
    val jsonStr = """[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]"""
    import spark.implicits._
    val df= spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonStr :: Nil))
    df.show()
    df.agg(*[concat_ws(",",collect_list(col(i))).alias(i) for i in df.columns])

Comment: @JayachandranNachimuthu please try below code.val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "collect_list")).toMap

df.agg(exprs).show()

Comment: Thanks, Mahesh. It's working now.     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JSON_Sample").master("local[1]") getOrCreate()

    val jsonStr = """[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":11,"b":12,"c":13},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]"""
    import spark.implicits._
    val df= spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonStr :: Nil))
    df.show()
    val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "collect_list")).toMap
    df.agg(exprs).show()

Comment: @JayachandranNachimuthu thanks for the update and you can accept this answer.